# dt dd with line breaks between

Tags: html, css

```html
<dl>
  <dt>hello</dt>
  <dd>bonjour</dd><br>

  <dt>goodbye</dt>
  <dd>aurevoir</dd><br>
</dl>
```

So I have a dl and I want each dt -> dd pair to show on one row so it is a line break between them. I feel like this css should solve it but it does not.

```
dd:after {
  content:"\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

I have tried putting each dt,dd pair in a p-element or with a br-element after whitch looks like I want but makes the HTML not validate.

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868591/8620333 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
dd,dt {
  display: inline;
}
dd::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
}
```

Solved it for me ty for comment.

Comment: Wow man, this is pure poetry! You are a genius, man. This answer need to receive more attention from the community!